# How to improve the page load time of a asp.net web site?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008, c#-3.0, performance-testing

Hi all i am using vs2008 c# asp.net. I have pages in my project which contains many gridviews list views and textboxes, image upload controls. all controls are from standard toolkit with vs2008. I want to know the possible means for improving the page load time for my project. I have heard about viewstate compression .any other suggestions? Please help. Thanks

Comment: @Russ cam can u please just tell what are the common technique names atlest.. like viewstate compression?

Comment: try using **repeater** instead **gridview** which is faster. Also have a look at this question which might give you some ideas **http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/84790/how-to-increase-the-speed-of-the-page-loading-in-asp-net**

Answer (score 1):

First thing you should do is measure current state, there are many tools to help you in this task :

- [Google page speed](https://developers.google.com/pagespeed/)
- [YSlow](http://yslow.org/)
- [Web page test](http://www.webpagetest.org/)
- [Pingdom tools](http://tools.pingdom.com/fpt/)
- [Fiddler 2](http://fiddler2.com/fiddler2/)
- [ViewState Size](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/viewstate-size/) - Firefox ext.
- [ViewState viewer](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/aspnet-viewstate-viewer/?src=api) - Firefox ext.

things that you need to measure

- what is the time to first byte, or time needed for server to generate page, it should be below 0.5 seconds. If this time is greater that this use Visual Studio profiler to locate bottlenecks and optimize critical parts
- Measure viewstate size and analyze contents, since you are using lots of gridviews, this is possibly the problem, here on SO there are dozens of [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1102385/asp-net-gridviews-viewstates) related to that problem
- **UNDERSTAND** ViewState, and how it's working, excellent post [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/infinitiesloop/archive/2006/08/03/Truly-Understanding-Viewstate.aspx)
- you should decrease number of requests, combine css and JavaScript in one file, there are plenty of [free tools to do that](https://www.google.com/#hl=en&output=search&sclient=psy-ab&q=combine+and+minify+&oq=combine+and+minify+&aq=f&aqi=g3&aql=&gs_nf=1&gs_l=hp.3..0l3.252.3002.0.3714.19.15.0.4.4.0.153.1751.4j11.19.0.aKxBz-wcA-I&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=8c7646f229469991&biw=1390&bih=909)
- Turn on IIS gzip compression
- Use fiddler to see how are your requests cached locally
- Use [Css Image Sprites](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_image_sprites.asp) for small images
- Use asp.net caching, it's really good and it offers solutions for many usage scenarios, especially helpful in situations where increased traffic is the problem

Answer (score 1):

Focus on optimizing the server side first. If you have "many grid views", depending upon how they are sourced (database, for example) you can try to improve the processing of your data access. Search for the appropriate optimization technique that makes sense for your application.

You could also try to reduce the number of grids. This may not be a possible option due to requirements.

You can also look at [moving your ViewState from the top of the page to the bottom](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/MovingViewStateToTheBottomOfThePage.aspx), along with the other standard client-side optimizations (reduce the number of resource calls, place css in the document head, scripts at the document end, enable client-side caching, etc...).

Answer (score 1):

**ViewState Chunking**

As an alternative to compression, you can look into chunking the ViewState, which is basically dividing the ViewState across several hidden fields instead of just one. This can yield a moderate improvement in overall page performance.

Check out this article: [Large ViewState & ViewState Chunking](http://weblogs.asp.net/jhallal/archive/2011/07/09/large-viewstate-amp-viewstate-chunking-maxpagestatefieldlength.aspx)

**Alternative Storage**

There are also several other ways you can store ViewState information other than a hidden field on the page.

Check out this article: [Manage ViewState Using ASP.NET 2.0 Provider Architecture](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18705/Manage-ViewState-Using-ASP-NET-2-0-Provider-Archit)

**ViewState Compression**

Personally, I've found that compressing the `ViewState` nets the biggest gains in terms of performance, so if it is a possibility I would definitely explore it. Telerik's [RadCompression](http://blogs.telerik.com/blogs/posts/09-02-27/optimization-tip-radcompression-for-viewstate.aspx) module works *great*, but it's not free. You can implement it yourself too though.

Check out these articles on ViewState compression:

- [Compressing ViewState in ASP.NET](http://geekswithblogs.net/pabothu/archive/2011/10/16/compressing-viewstate-in-asp.net.aspx)
- [ViewState Compression](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14733/ViewState-Compression)

Lastly, wherever you don't need to track ViewState, set `EnableViewState` to false.

Answer (score -1):

- ViewState Mode could be set to false

Even if you are using heavy weight controls, they might not require to have the ViewState "enabled". So, try to identify when you don't actually need them and set up the ViewStateMode property to false in each of them:

```
ViewStateMode="Disabled"
```

This would reduce the size of the ViewState so that the performance can be improved

- gzip Compression

By following this [tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/186233/Utilize-gzip-compression-in-IIS) you can set up the ViewState compression to reduce its size and increase the website performance

- Monitor your ViewState size

By using this Mozilla [add-on](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/viewstate-size/), you can monitor the size of your ViewState and see if this is the actual cause of the website's slowness since this could also be related to sql queries or other reasons different to the ViewState